# session-set-cookie-params path non working

Tags: php, session

I created two files:

```
// /var/www/blah/index.php (www.example.com/blah/index.php)

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/blah'); 
session_start();   
$_SESSION['hello'] = 1;
```

and

```
// /var/www/foo/index.php  (www.example.com/foo/index.php)

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/foo'); 
session_start();   
echo $_SESSION['hello'];
```

When opening the first, then the second in browser, I get `1`.

Why is the same `SESSION` available in both?

It should not, according to [session-set-cookie-params](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

Comment: It is not. How did you test?

Comment: @AlexBlex: I edited to show the test.

Comment: Your code example is flawed. That implies that you didn't copy your real code and your example is probably flawed and you overlooked something. It should work exactly as described.

Comment: Did you clear cookies before test? /foo/index.php shows me a notice that hello is undefined. Do you have any rewrite rules? What do you see if you put `echo __DIR__;` right after `session_start` in both files?

Comment: @AlexBlex The problem is solved already, see my answer.

Comment: @Xatenev, whew, thanks god it is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in ##php on freenode:

The browser doesn't respect the `session_set_cookie_params()` because you have a valid `PHPSESSID cookie` and your browser keeps regenerating it. (because you visited the page before). Delete all your `PHPSESSID cookies` and try again.

Comment: Indeed, after a few things like this + `session_destroy();` it finally worked.